# How do I pass an anonymous subroutines when calling a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, arguments, anonymous-function

`mysub` gets a subroutine reference as its first argument.

Can I simply call `mysub(sub{some  subroutine body here})` ? I.e. define an anonymous subroutine right at the call?

Is the syntax OK (is it really a reference to `sub` that is passed)?

Comment: I tried it and it worked (otherwise I wouldn't even asked), BUT I recall a few instances from my history when I tested something I have "invented" in Perl and it seemed to work, but later I discovered it actually worked only for the specific cases I have testes, and the general idea/syntax I used was plain wrong... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happened when you tried it? That's surely the best way to test whether things like this work.

But, yes, that syntax will work just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub run_sub {
  shift->();
}

run_sub( sub { print "hello\n"; } );
```

Answer (score 5):

Since passing subroutine references to other subroutines is a fairly common pattern, Perl even has a few syntax tricks to make it even smoother:

```
sub function1 {          # normal declaration, implicit `(@)` prototype
    my $code = shift;
    $code->(@_);
}

sub function2 (&@) {     # prototyped declaration
    my $code = shift;
    $code->(@_);
}
```

`function1` has to be called as: `function1 sub{...}, any_other_args`

`function2` has the prototype `(&@)` which tells the compiler to impose subroutine context on the first argument (and then accept any number of additional arguments).

So you can call it as `function2 {...} any_other_args` which mirrors the way the higher order builtins like `map`, `grep`, and `sort` take their code blocks.  Note that there is no comma after the code block, just like with the bultins.

You can find more information about prototypes here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes

Keep in mind that Perl's prototypes are NOT for argument validation, they are hints to the compiler that allow you to write subroutines that behave like builtins.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (to the answer by [@davorg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/davorg)), you can use:

```
sub run_sub
{
    my($funcref) = @_;
    &$funcref();
}
```

More verbose, certainly; also a little clearer, I think.  But this is Perl - TMTOWTDI!

Comment: `$funcref->()` is a little more Modern Perlish, but I think they are absolutely identical.

Comment: They're not identical.  The `&foo` (or `&$foo` in this case of a coderef) syntax can circumvent prototypes.

Comment: @Simon Both `&$foo` and `$foo->()` will circumvent prototypes. From 
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes: "prototypes have no influence on subroutine references like `\&foo` or on indirect subroutine calls like `&{$subref}` or `$subref->()`."